# Why should Blockdim be the same for all blocks in a grid in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

Why is `blockDim`, the total number of threads in a block, the same for all blocks in a grid in a CUDA program? I know that if the block size is the same for all blocks, indexing would be very easy, but if I have blocks with size multiples of 32 (for warps) but in an increasing order, maybe AP or GP indexing is very easy.

What is the reasoning for making all blocks of a grid the same size?

Comment: What AP and GP indexing?

Comment: Its a limitation of CUDA. Is there an appropriate SO coding question here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple blocks of different sizes all running the same kernel, it's highly likely that larger blocks take longer on an SM than smaller blocks. This would slow your code significantly compared to an evenly distributed work-load. In a way, they're preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot.

I would also hazard a guess that it simplifies their memory management immensely - with a uniform block size, each block needs a fixed amount of shared memory/registers etc to be allocated on an SM.

Variable block size seems possible, but unwarranted. If you're worried about doing useless work on a block, don't be. Just take an early exit out of the block if you're outside of your grid - the performance hit is miniscule.